# File processing in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Is Erlang good option for file processing of different types? For example- reading pdf,Word document,Excel sheet and transforming them? I know we can use Apache POI/Tika which are Java based and then integrate using JErlang. 
I am not very familiar with Erlang's bit syntax but wanted to check if Erlang is suited for such kind of application without using Apache POI?

Answer (score 2):

Erlang has a great [binary support](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html) which makes it a great language for parsing different kind of binaries.

i.e. to [decode a tcp segment by using binary syntax in erlang](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/the-power-of-erlang-bit-syntax.html) you can do something like

```
decode(Segment) ->
    case Segment of 
    << SourcePort:16, DestinationPort:16,
       SequenceNumber:32,
       AckNumber:32,
       DataOffset:4, _Reserved:4, Flags:8, WindowSize:16,
       Checksum:16, UrgentPointer:16,
       Payload/binary>> when DataOffset>4
    ->
        OptSize = (DataOffset - 5)*32,
        << Options:OptSize, Message/binary >> = Payload,
        <> = <>,
        %% Can now process the Message according to the
        %% Options (if any) and the flags CWR, ..., FIN. 
        binary_to_list(Message)
    end.
```

which compared to other languages is a super easy way to use pattern matching and binary support to decode/encode binaries.

Nevertheless, Erlang is more about concurrent processing and message passing between those processes, so I wouldn't use it to transform/parse binaries, I would instead use Erlang to manage the web server/api and to handle all the concurrent connections, and I would delegate the job of transforming the documents to raw c/c++ for performance, plus on c/c++ or either on java you have richer libraries to work with pdf/excel/word documents

Comment: Thanks. Won't Erlang to C++ delegation affects performance? We may not have millisecond SLA so I was thinking if we can do entire thing in Erlang?

Comment: At that point you should really do benchmarks to decide whether to go C/C++ or Erlang, in my experience transforming binary documents has better performance when handled by c/c++ than erlang/beam, you can build ports to use c/c++ from erlang: http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html and you can also implement unix sockets to call c/c++ from erlang which is also pretty fast, the real problem is not on the communication from Erlang to c/c++ but on the time/cpu required by erlang to parse millions of binary documents.